# Find a CFG for $\{a^n b^m c^k \mid m=n+k\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am trying to build the CFG to $\{a^n b^m c^k \mid m=n+k\}$ but does not working.

I tried $S \to aSc$, $S \to S_1$, $S \to \epsilon$, $S_1 \to bS_1c$, $S_1 \to \epsilon$ but it does not work.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I guess that I done `S → aSc S → S1 S → e S1 → bS1c S1 → e` @DonThousand

Comment: You don't want $S\to aSc$  This increases the number of $a$'s and $c$'s and leaves the number of $b$'s fixed.  Every time you add an $a$ or a $c$ you must add a $b$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that your language can be written as the product of two context-free languages
$$
\{a^nb^{n+k}c^k \mid n, k \geqslant 0 \} = \{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}\{b^kc^k \mid k \geqslant 0\}
$$
which naturally leads to the grammar
\begin{align}
S &\to S_0S_1 \\
S_0 &\to aS_0b + 1 \\
S_1 &\to bS_1c + 1
\end{align}

Comment: The $+1$ seems like an odd notation.  Don’t you mean $\mid \epsilon$ or something similar?

Comment: @Erick_Wong This is just the algebraic notation, which seems appropriate for a Math site. $1$ denotes the identity of the free monoid, that is the empty word. The $+$ notation is natural when you associate an equation to the grammar. For instance, the language $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ is the least solution of the equation $S = aSb + 1$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the explanation (I hadn't seen Chomsky's paper on CFG algebras before).  It still seems like a mixed metaphor to use the algebraic notation on the RHS in conjunction with the production rule arrow rather than a more conventional equals sign.